# how to update a deeply nested object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nested

I have a this type of a json object.

```
{
    "id": "001",
    "type": "A",
    "value": "aaaaa",
    "data:": {},
    "path": ["001"],
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "002",
            "type": "A",
            "value": "aaaaa",
            "data:": {},
            "path": ["001", "002"],
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "003",
            "type": "A",
            "value": "aaaaa",
            "data:": {},
            "path": ["001", "003"],
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "00001",
                    "type": "B",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "004",
            "type": "A",
            "value": "aaaaa",
            "data:": {},
            "path": ["001", "004"],
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "005",
                    "type": "A",
                    "value": "aaaaa",
                    "data:": {},
                    "path": ["001", "004", "005"],
                    "children": []
                },{
                    "id": "005",
                    "type": "A",
                    "value": "aaaaa",
                    "data:": {},
                    "path": ["001", "004", "005"],
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "00002",
                            "type": "B",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "00003",
            "type": "B",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to replace all the object which is `type: "B"` , with this (which is mentioned below) type of object which I can get from an object with ids as keys of typed B. This typed B objects can be nested anywhere either as a first child or fifth child of a nested arrays of children

```
{
    "id": "002",
    "type": "A",
    "value": "aaaaa",
    "data:": {},
    "children": []
},
```

How can I do that? This can be deeply nested and there's no specific place where we should replace the objects, beforehand. So, I need to go through the entire object and do that. How should I get it done?

**EDIT**

I updated the code in the question slightly. There's a path property of the nested in each object, except for typed **B** objects. So, when replacing the typed B properties with the other object, I need to add the paths in there as well.

eg: path for id: "00001", typed B object should be : ["001", "003", "00001"]

EDIT :
Expected result

```
{
    "id": "001",
    "type": "A",
    "value": "aaaaa",
    "data:": {},
    "path": ["001"],
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "002",
            "type": "A",
            "value": "aaaaa",
            "data:": {},
            "path": ["001", "002"],
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "003",
            "type": "A",
            "value": "aaaaa",
            "data:": {},
            "path": ["001", "003"],
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "002",
                    "type": "A",
                    "value": "aaaaa",
                    "data:": {},
                    "path": ["001", "003", "002"],
                    "children": []
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "004",
            "type": "A",
            "value": "aaaaa",
            "data:": {},
            "path": ["001", "004"],
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "005",
                    "type": "A",
                    "value": "aaaaa",
                    "data:": {},
                    "path": ["001", "004", "005"],
                    "children": []
                },{
                    "id": "005",
                    "type": "A",
                    "value": "aaaaa",
                    "data:": {},
                    "path": ["001", "004", "005"],
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "002",
                            "type": "A",
                            "value": "aaaaa",
                            "data:": {},
                            "path": ["001", "004", "005", "002"],
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "002",
            "type": "A",
            "value": "aaaaa",
            "data:": {},
            "path": ["001", "002"],
            "children": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Likely a recursive function; what's the specific issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing a function deeply nested inside an object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327168/replacing-a-function-deeply-nested-inside-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you @Kinglish . But in this case, I don't know where it should be replaced beforehand rather than going inside all the paths in the object. So, I think it's not straightforward as mentioned in that answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you. Yes. I'm implementing a recursive function for this. But since I don't know where to be replaced beforehand, I need to go through all the paths in the object. Was wondering whether there's any other approach or similar scenarios

Comment: That's the recursive part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**lodash** if you don't mind.

Use [cloneDeepWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeepWith) to clone the entire tree and replace a specific value.

```js
const data = {"id":"001","type":"A","value":"aaaaa","data:":{},"children":[{"id":"002","type":"A","value":"aaaaa","data:":{},"children":[]},{"id":"003","type":"A","value":"aaaaa","data:":{},"children":[{"id":"00001","type":"B","children":[]}]},{"id":"004","type":"A","value":"aaaaa","data:":{},"children":[{"id":"005","type":"A","value":"aaaaa","data:":{},"children":[]},{"id":"005","type":"A","value":"aaaaa","data:":{},"children":[{"id":"00002","type":"B","children":[]}]}]},{"id":"00003","type":"B","children":[]}]};

const result = _.cloneDeepWith(data, (value) => {
  const newObj = {"id": "002", "type": "A", "value": "---NEW VALUE FOR 'B' TYPE---", "data:": {} };
  return (value.type === 'B') ? { ...value, ...newObj} : _.noop();
});


console.dir(result, { depth: null } );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.js" integrity="sha512-2iwCHjuj+PmdCyvb88rMOch0UcKQxVHi/gsAml1fN3eg82IDaO/cdzzeXX4iF2VzIIes7pODE1/G0ts3QBwslA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

**--- Update 2---** (Without lodash)

Use local variable to store and combine current path.

```js
const data = { "id": "001", "type": "A", "value": "aaaaa", "data:": {}, "path": ["001"], "children": [{ "id": "002", "type": "A", "value": "aaaaa", "data:": {}, "path": ["001", "002"], "children": [] }, { "id": "003", "type": "A", "value": "aaaaa", "data:": {}, "path": ["001", "003"], "children": [{ "id": "00001", "type": "B", "children": [] }] }, { "id": "004", "type": "A", "value": "aaaaa", "data:": {}, "path": ["001", "004"], "children": [{ "id": "005", "type": "A", "value": "aaaaa", "data:": {}, "path": ["001", "004", "005"], "children": [] }, { "id": "005", "type": "A", "value": "aaaaa", "data:": {}, "path": ["001", "004", "005"], "children": [{ "id": "00002", "type": "B", "children": [] }] }] }, { "id": "00003", "type": "B", "children": [] }] }

const deepReplace = (obj, prevPath = []) => {
    if (obj.type === 'A') {
      if  (obj.children.length) {
        obj.children = obj.children.map((childObj) => deepReplace(childObj, obj.path))
      }
      return obj;
    };
    if (obj.type === 'B') {
      const id = '002';
      return { id, type: "A", value: "aaaaa",  path: [...prevPath, id],  data: {}, children: []};
    };
 };

console.dir(deepReplace(data), { depth: null });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Thank you,. this works. However, for type B objects, I need to update a property based on the parent's object as well . That's what I'm trying to figure out now.

Comment: @ThidasaPankaja, can you please update the question what result you expect.

Comment: updated with the expected result

Comment: Your edited answer seems to work almost. But for the final item (which was in type ``B``, id ``0003`` ) it returns ``['001', '004', '005', '00002', '00003']`` as the path instead of ``path: (5) ['001', '00003']``

Comment: @ThidasaPankaja, yes I see the problem. Try to solve it, just a bit latter.

Comment: @ThidasaPankaja, check second update

Comment: Perfect.
It works

Comment: @ThidasaPankaja, Happy to help! Mark this as accepted, please.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a tree traversal problem. Here's a way to handle that with [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_search) without recursion.

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3776051/4282081) answer, recursion should be avoided whenever possible, as it requires more memory and is more difficult to debug than an iterative implementation.

**Updated per adjustment in question**

```js
const data = {"id":"001","type":"A","value":"aaaaa","data:":{},"path":["001"],"children":[{"id":"002","type":"A","value":"aaaaa","data:":{},"path":["001","002"],"children":[]},{"id":"003","type":"A","value":"aaaaa","data:":{},"path":["001","003"],"children":[{"id":"00001","type":"B","children":[]}]},{"id":"004","type":"A","value":"aaaaa","data:":{},"path":["001","004"],"children":[{"id":"005","type":"A","value":"aaaaa","data:":{},"path":["001","004","005"],"children":[]},{"id":"005","type":"A","value":"aaaaa","data:":{},"path":["001","004","005"],"children":[{"id":"00002","type":"B","children":[]}]}]},{"id":"00003","type":"B","children":[]}]};

const dfs = () => {
  const stack = [[data, null]];
  
  while(stack.length) {
    const [curr, parent] = stack.pop();
    // check for match on type
    if (curr.type === "B") {
      curr.type = "A";
      curr.id = "002";
      curr.value = "aaaaa";
      curr.data = {};
      curr.path = [...parent?.path.slice() ?? [], "002"];
    }
    curr.children.forEach(child => stack.push([child, curr]));
  }
};

dfs();

const output = document.getElementById("output");
output.innerText = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="output" />
```

Comment: Thank you. this works. However, for type B objects, I need to update a property based on the parent's object as well . That's what I'm trying to figure out now.

Comment: @ThidasaPankaja Updated answer based on this info.

Comment: This is perfect

Answer (score 1):

I played around with this in the console and it did what you wanted (based on the json array provided, setting all the "B" to "A" types). It's a recursive function so on any nested child it meets in the "children" array it would call the function again on each item in the array.

```js
function fixObjects (obj) {
  if (obj["type"] === "B") {
    obj["type"] = "A";
    obj["id"] = "002";
    obj["value"] = "aaaaa";
    obj["data"] = {};
  } 
  if (obj["children"].length > 0) {
     obj["children"].forEach (child => fixObjects (child));
  }
}

fixObjects (_yourArray)
```

Comment: Thank you. this works. However, for type B objects, I need to update a property based on the parent's object as well . That's what I'm trying to figure out now.